# 'sign' vs 'notice'

Tags: comparison

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the words 'sign' and 'notice'? The definitions in Cambridge Online Dictionary are:

- sign : a symbol or message in a public place that gives information or instructions
- notice : a sign giving information about something

Comment: For me a sign has some permanency, it is made of something that is long lasting. For example road signs. A notice often has a shorter life, it may be a piece of paper.

Comment: Also, a sign may be just a name, or something like TICKET OFFICE or TOILETS. A notice usually contains a longer piece of information, or instructions on what to do or what not to do.

Comment: A sign can be expressed in symbols of any kind (skull and crossbones, a hangman's noose, a white flag, a guard dog); a notice is generally set out in words.